# Laravel Forge Public Key Access Denied

Tags: laravel, ssh-keys, laravel-forge

I am trying to ssh into my application from the command line however I am having issue with the ssh public key.

1st => I tried using PUTTTY to generate keys and save with appropriate name and extension `id_rsa.pub` which seem to work great

2nd => I ran this command `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to copy key and place it in the ssh key option on the laravel forge dashboard

3rd => I ran `ssh forge@my_id_address` and it threw an alarm saying public key access denied

So then I found this website [Click Here](https://forge.besnappy.com/laravel-forge) and followed the steps using the Git Bash command line to generate keys

The command `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "my_email@example.com"` which worked to generate keys however I was unable to create passphrase??

Next I pasted the public key in the laravel forge dashboard

And then I used `ssh forge@my-ip-address -i ~/.ssh/your-key` as suggested and got the following alarm

```
Load key "/c/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub": invalid format
forge@my_ip_address: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have seen this as a common issue I guess but no luck with suggested fixes, any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

I had to use `start-ssh-agent`. After that I was able to ssh into the application with the previous command `ssh forge@my-ip-address -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`